# Drupal - Use Print module to create pdf from drupal page with custom link

Tags: drupal, print-module

Hi I am using Print module to print node to pdf. I try to add print_pdf_insert_link() into my template, but php says, that this is undefined function. Print module is enabled and all permissions are set. I am using version 7.x-1.2. Am I missing something?

Comment: have u installed either : dompdf
mPDF (only in the 7.x-2.x branch)
TCPDF
wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I installed dompdf. Need I install all of them?

Comment: no one is fine.  its very strange can't help with such limited access sorry. unless you can find a way to share more info.